# Pyautogui reference resolution does not match to screenshot

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

So I wrote a script for a game that runs on emulator. Using pyautogui but the emulator window size different everytime. So the "locateonscreen" function only working when the reference image is same resolution as screenshot shot image (or the image captured by the pyautogui). So how can I fix this by making the reference image relative to any size of the match on the screen.